# How to read XML file? Google App Engine Endpoints

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, sax, google-cloud-endpoints

I got:

```
wordsDictionary.xml
```

in:

```
/WEB-INF/xml/
```

and I'm trying to read it with `SAXReader` using code:

```
...
SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxFactory.setValidating(false);
saxFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
XMLReader reader = saxFactory.getXMLReader();
reader.setContentHandler(new WordsDictionarySAXHandler(this,lettersMapping));
reader.parse(new InputSource("/WEB-INF/xml/wordsDictionary.xml"));
...
```

On Dev server everything goes fine. When deploying it to production I'm getting an error:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: access denied
("java.io.FilePermission" "/WEB-INF/xml/wordsDictionary.xml" "read")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission"  
"/WEBINF/xml/wordsDictionary.xml" "read")
```

Before you say that I need to use: `context.getResourceAsStream`
you need to know I'm using **Google Endpoints**. So I don't have access to any directly **Servlet** (nothing is passed to endpoint method - `HttpRequest`).

My question is: Do you know how to load xml file right on GAE Endpoints?

**EDIT:**
Just read https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java?csw=1#readfile:

> If the file location is not the issue, the problem may be that the
>   method you are using to read from the file is not whitelisted. Your
>   application can use any IO classes that are useful for reading from
>   the file system, such as File, FileInputStream, FileReader, or
>   RandomAccessFile. For a full list of whitelisted classes, please see
>   the JRE Class White List.

I've changed part of code to:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/WEB-INF/xml/wordsDictionary.xml");
reader.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(stream)));
```

Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason of error was "/" before WEB-INF. 
Remember:

```
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission"  
"/WEBINF/xml/wordsDictionary.xml" "read")
```

This error can be thrown even when you're trying to access a bad directory.

Also remember to set proper encoding for your XML files:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("WEB-INF/xml/wordsDictionary.xml");
InputSource is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
reader.parse(is);
```